# dojo 1.5 wizards?

Tags: grails, spring-webflow, dojo

I have been looking around for a wizard that can be implemented via dojo... I saw one in dojox but I'm having issues mostly because the sample I saw in [the test wizard in the dojo archives](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/widget/tests/test_Wizard.html) used wizard panes to separate each page... but it was all coded in a single page!

Now, I have 6 pages (gsp/jsp pages) that are coded separately (using a webflow in grails) and should be loaded separately in a dialog-type of control because they have inter-dependencies (e.g. page 2 needs values from page 1). Is this possible in the dojo wizard? Or are there any other (javascript or other) libraries I can use for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the grails [ajaxflow plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/ajaxflow) is what you're looking for. From what I can tell it uses jQuery under the hood but I don't suppose that is a showstopper for you.

Comment: Hmm, looks interesting... I'll check that one out, thanks! :)